# Dropdown inside overflow hidden container

Tags: html, css

If a dropdown is inside a scrollable container. How to avoid the dropdown being clipped by the overflow property?

Have found a lot of solutions, but none with a working example

It's possible to do with javascript, but the internet claims it's possible with pure CSS.. But can't make it work

The dropdown has to follow when you scroll the grey container with overflow

```css
.main {
  background: grey;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.dropdown-container {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
    test<br>test
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <div class="dropdown">dropdown content</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: which element do you click or hover on to show the dropdown? your code doesn't show that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make it work with css only,
you have to use the parent div (dropdown-container) as absolute position
like:

```css
.main{
  position:static;
  background:grey;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  padding:5px;
  margin:20px;
  overflow:auto;
}

.dropdown-container {
  position:absolute;
  margin:0 10px;
  background:red;
  width:100px;
  height:200px;
  color:white;
  z-index: 2000;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
    test<br>test
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <div class="dropdown">dropdown content</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: now the dropdown doesn't follow the scroll

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but if you change the `position:absolute` to `position:relative` for the `.dropdown` class, you will not have this problem of dropdown clipped and you will be able to scroll inside the scrollable container.

```
.dropdown{
  position:relative;
  margin:0 10px;
  background:blue;
  width:100px;
  height:200px;
  color:white;
}
```

Comment: No, I want the dropdown to be on top of the content..

Comment: If you place your dropdown-container div in first position inside the main div, it will be on the top

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `dropdown-container` to follow the grey container when you scroll, this can be your solution (if not, please do comment and I can try a different method).

```css
.main {
  background: grey;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.dropdown-container {
  position: sticky;
  top: 5px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>test<br />test</div>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <div class="dropdown">dropdown content</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test
  </div>
</div>
```

But as the dropdown will likely appear as a result of a click event(it won't be visible all the time) so the below solution seems more practical where you'll also be able to fully view you dropdown container.

```css
.main {
  background: grey;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.dropdown-container {
  position: sticky;
  top: 5px;
}

.dropdown {
  /* position: absolute; */
  margin: 0 10px;
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>test<br />test</div>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <div class="dropdown">dropdown content</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test
  </div>
</div>
```